# OpenLDAP never starts replicating with syncrepl

Tags: openldap

I have setup ldap replication via the offical tutorial of Ubuntu 14.04 server:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-installation

The replication seems to be not working and not starting ! I added some new users so that they could sync, but these are not replicated.

The following command shows how far the replication is :

On the Provider:  ldapsearch -z1 -LLLQY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -s base -b dc=expample,dc=com contextCSN

contextCSN: 20150212213757.067885Z#000000#000#000000

On the consumer: ldapsearch -z1 -LLLQY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -s base -b dc=example,dc=com contextCSN

Here I got nothing back...

Can somebody help me with that?

Kr,

Joeri

Comment: Off topic, and about 90% of the required information is missing. You would have to post the relevant configuration extracts on both master and slave. Try serverfault.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution:
In the consumer LDIF that needs to be imported i had to put everything on one line of the "olcSyncRepl" part... I had some issues due too the spaces.

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=0 provider=ldap://openldap0101.example.com bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" credentials=secret searchbase="dc=example,dc=com" logbase="cn=accesslog" logfilter="(&(objectClass=auditWriteObject)(reqResult=0))" schemachecking=on type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" syncdata=accesslog
-
add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://openldap0101.example.com
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it relies on secret information that only you knew, and failed to post here when requested. Usefulness to others of this question and answer is zero.